# If all python methods are indeed non-data descriptors can I overwrite a method.__get__?

Tags: python

I just realized that all user defined functions have a `__get__` that allows the function to operate as descriptors when the functions are used in a class. This `__get__` returns a `<bound method object>` when invoked in the context of an instance (`myinstance.method`) and returns the original function when invoked in the context of class (`MyClass.method`).

I was trying to get methods to behave like attributes (in the same way as with `@property` but without the side effect of data descriptor, i.e non-overridable from instances). I succeeded by creating a non-data descriptor that just invokes the original method on `__get__` but when I discover that functions are already descriptors I tried to change the function's `__get__` to do the invocation directly instead of returning a `<bound method ...>` but without luck.

Here is my try:

```
class A(object):
    def m(self):
        self.m = 20 # to show that .m is overridable at instance level
        return 10


def alternative__get(self, instance, owner):
    if instance is None:
        return self
    else:
        return self.__func__(instance)

print(A.__dict__['m'].__get__)  # => <method-wrapper '__get__' of function object ...>
A.__dict__['m'].__get__ = alternative__get
print(A.__dict__['m'])  # <function m ..>
print(A.__dict__['m'].__get__) # <function alternative__get ...>
print(A.m)  # <unbound method A.m>
a = A()
print(a.m)  # <bound method A.m of ...>
print(a.m)  # <bound method A.m of ...>
```

This doesn have the desired effect `a.m` still resolves to `<bound method...>` instead of returning directly the result of invoking `A.m(a)`.

My current approach is to define a descriptor:

```
class attribute(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return self.fget(instance)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @attribute
    def m(self):
        self.m = 20;
        return 10


a = A()
print(a.m) # => 10
# a.m = 30
print(a.m) # => 20 because it's overriden at instance level
```

This approach works but I would like to know if it's possible to change `A.m.__get__` to achieve the same effect, or **why** it can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this by setting `A.m.__get__`, because the Python language internals skip the instance dict when looking up special methods like `__get__`. (This is so, for example, a class `Foo` that defines a `__repr__` method uses `type.__repr__` instead of `Foo.__repr__` when you do `repr(Foo)`.)